# Is anything wrong with my JavaScript format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm on a .NET MVC2 project and have a reference to SomeClass.Home.js and jQuery in the masterpage. My SomeClass.Home.js looks like this:

```
SomeClass.Home = {};

$(document).ready(function () {
    SomeClass.Home.SomeMethod();    
});

SomeClass.Home.SomeMethod= function () {
    alert("hello");
};
```

The call to `SomeClass.Home.SomeMethod` doesn't work (I don't get the alert). However, if I change it to this, it works, and I get the alert:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    SomeMethod();    
});

function SomeMethod () {
    alert("hello");
};
```

Is anything wrong with the syntax of the first one?

Comment: Firebug Console will show a ReferenceError with the "SomeClass.Home = {};" statement, claiming that SomeClass is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the way you described the SomeClass variable.  The following code works for me.

```
var SomeClass = {};
SomeClass.Home = {};
SomeClass.Home.SomeMethod = function() {
  alert("hello");
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    SomeClass.Home.SomeMethod();    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because you're not declaring the method. I believe you should do it like this:

```
SomeClass.Home = {
   SomeMethod = function(){ //stuff });
}

$(function(){ SomeClass.Home.SomeMethod() });
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you embed the function in the class?

```
SomeClass.Home = {
  SomeMethod= function () {
    alert("hello");
  };
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    SomeClass.Home.SomeMethod();    
});

SomeClass.Home.SomeMethod= function () {
    alert("hello");
};
```

Comment: Also, why is this post tagged with C#?

Comment: Removed the c# and .net tag. It was by habit.